# Can't access main setting ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, system-settings, phpmyadmin

While trying to setup phpmyadmin on my ubuntu I noticed i have lost main settings option from my system. Please help me out.
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy7vH.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clnia.png)
[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH8of.png)
[Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ1MY.png)

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: First , I completely removed mysql-server and phpmyadmin and reinstalled. Then, I noticed I don't have main settings. My attached screenshot should give you some clue.

Comment: Try sudo apt install -f  . And then re-install gnome-settings

Comment: Can you check if you removed "gnome-settings" package while removing mysql-server and phpmyadmin?

Comment: How do i check if i have removed it? -framontb

Comment: -Parsa Mousavi I tried sudo apt install -f. It comes out with errors. Check screenshot 3.

Comment: @noob124 Run "sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq phpmyadmin"  to temporarily delete the broken phpmyadmin package . Then run "sudo apt update " and re-install gnome settings and phpmyadmin .

Comment: @Parsa Mousavi It still returns with the same 'error exit status 127'. Check screenshot 4. Snap store returns same screenshot 2 error.

Comment: In the error it states that it cannot open the file "/usr/share/dbconfig-common/internal /mysql" possibly because it's not there at all . Can you install the mysql-server again and then delete the phpmyadmin ?

Comment: @Parsa Mousavi Still returns with the same 'error exit status 127' as in screenshot 4.

Comment: @noob124 Does method 2 and 5 [here](https://appuals.com/fix-unmet-dependencies-error-ubuntu/) help you ?

Comment: Nope! It did not sadly.